# facebook api get users tagged_places

Tags: facebook

I want to know if there is a way to get through facebook api information about the tagged places of my friends without asking them for permission?
furthermore can I get the tagged places of users that are not in my friends list.

Comment: `"without asking them for permission"` - yea... umm... I don't think that Facebook would make this easy if at all possible for you. Would you want people to know this information about you `"without asking [you] for permission"`?

Comment: For users that are not my friends i think it doesn"t make sense but what about users that are in my friend list?

Comment: Friend list or not - you need to request permission to view any details about any user. The fact that the user is in your friend list doesn't exempt you from the permissions restrictions.

Comment: It sounds like you want spyware, and your question shows no research effort or code. How exactly is anybody supposed to help with this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this was once possible using the `/checkin` endpoint however at this point in time it looks like this method is no longer available.

Taken from the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/checkin):

> This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v1.0.

From the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api), you can see that this feature was totally removed:

> #### Endpoints no longer available in v2.0:
>
> - ...
> - `/me/checkins` has been removed, along with the `user_checkins` permission.
> - ...

Further down in the document they continue to list the permissions that have been removed:

> All `friends_*` permissions have been removed. They include:
>
> - ...
> - `friends_checkins`
> - ...

It seems that it is simply no longer possible to access the data you need. FYI this changelog information was [posted on April 30th, 2014](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0) - so it's been like this for a while.